# Can't access a global variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a global variable in `testGlob1`, however I'm not able to do so:

```
var displayVar;

function globVariable(){
    displayVar="2";
}

function testGlob1(){
    alert(displayVar);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? You never _called_ `testGlob1` in your code, so you have no observable behaviour.

Comment: Looks fine so far -- as fine as using globals ever looks... ;-)

Comment: i checked by calling the function like <input type="button" value="basicC2" onclick="testGlob1();">

Comment: Try using window.displayVar + when did you call globVariable() ?

Comment: @user2149501: And when did you ever call `globVariable()`?

Comment: @user2149501: Then you need to call `globVariable()` at some point in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't showing how your variable is being assigned a value.  Is globVariable() being called on load of the document?  Im sure this would work:

```
var displayVar=2;

function testGlob1(){
   alert(displayVar);   
}
```